# lubuntu - maximize windows by dragging to top

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, window-manager, window

I currently installed Lubuntu 12.04 on a Laptop to save resources compared to Ubuntu. I am missing the ability to maximize windows by dragging them to the top of the screen with the mouse. Is it possible to enable on Lubuntu? If it is, will it offset the resource savings that I got from choosing the LXDE desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the "cost" in terms of resource usage because I don't use it, but there is an **additional** piece of software that you could install to get what you ask for. It is called `Opensnap` and a write-up and installation directions are at [Opensnap (Aerosnap with mouse)](http://lubuntublog.blogspot.in/p/opensnap.html).

> Aerosnap is a lacking feature of the Openbox window manager, which
>   handles Lubuntu's windows, so we need to draw upon a "keystroke trick"
>   (see Aerosnap article) or use a 3rd party app. And there's a handy
>   program (thanks to lawl) that will do that, called Opensnap.

The impression I get from [the github page](https://github.com/lawl/opensnap) is that you may need to install `wmctrl` as well.

As I said, I haven't used it. I prefer not to add extra software if I can do what I want with existing resources such as the keyboard. [Reposition and Resize Windows Without Using a Mouse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#Reposition_and_Resize_Windows_Without_Using_a_Mouse) has suggestions on how to position windows using existing resources and the keyboard (not mouse).

The method I use to maximize windows is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>spacebar</kbd> together to get a dropdown and then type <kbd>x</kbd> to maximize. Other options are also available in the dropdown. Of course, you can assign an even more convenient keyboard shortcut in `lubuntu-rc.xml`.

Comment: Resource usage for opensnap is pretty modest, about 2MiB of RAM and <0.5% CPU load at all times on a standard Core i5 system. `wmctrl` is an obligatory dependency. Another tip: unsnapping doesn't work out of the box but can be activated either by [installing a development branch](https://github.com/lawl/opensnap/tree/unsnap) or introducing [a small modification to your `lubuntu-rc.xml`](https://github.com/lawl/opensnap/issues/4#issuecomment-23666097).

Comment: `wmctrl` isn't exactly obligatory. You just need it if you decide to go with the default configuration. Here's someone using a config without `wmctrl`: https://github.com/lawl/opensnap/issues/15