# Window snapping in Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: lubuntu, 13.10

I read that window snapping will be a default feature in Lubuntu 13.10. However, I've installed it and I don't have it. Perhaps it's disabled by default? How would one enable it?

Comment: Questions about 13.10 aren't really encouraged here. Would you like to ask at ubuntuforums.org instead? By the way, because I use Lubuntu as well, could you please post a link to where you read about window snapping by default? I'm assuming you're referring to mouse-base window snapping?

Comment: For what's "on-topic" check out http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [link](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fiwinuxfeed.altervista.org%2Faggregatore%2Faero-snap-approdera-su-lubuntu-13-10-saucy%2F&act=url) I read it yesterday in english, but for some reason, I can't find the source.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. However, I do follow news about Lubuntu development and do not get the impression that such mouse-based aerosnap will feature by default in Lubuntu 13.10.

Comment: http://lubuntublog.blogspot.com/p/opensnap.html points to a ppa that needs to be installed. Also see http://askubuntu.com/q/344800/25656

Comment: @vasa1 thank you for the link. Can one install that in Lubuntu 13.04, or does it need to be in 13.10?

Comment: I understand that it works for 13.04.

Comment: I did it in Lubuntu 13.04 and it doesn't work. Nothing changed.

Comment: Then you may wish to file a bug [here](https://launchpad.net/~lawl/+archive/opensnap) or raise an issue [here](https://github.com/lawl/opensnap/issues/15).